# Octave Parallel Code Example

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, octave

Can anyone provide an example octave code to submit to the cluster assuming the parallel package for octave is installed in the cluster? What I am saying, do I just use parfor as in Matlab parallel computing toolbox, or use something like the code below?

```
n = 100000000;
s = 0;
% Initialize MPI
MPI_Init;
% Create MPI communicator
comm= MPI_COMM_WORLD;
% Get size and rank
size = MPI_Comm_size(comm);
rank= MPI_Comm_rank(comm);
master = 0;
% Split the for loop into size partitions
m = n / size;
r = mod(n, m);
if ( rank == size-1 )
    se = (rank + 1)*m + r;
else
  se = (rank + 1)*m;
end
% Each process works on a partition of the loop independently
s1 = s;
for i=(rank * m)+1:se
    s1 = s1 + i;
end
% print the partial summation on each process
disp(['Partial summation: ', num2str(s1), ' on process ', num2str(rank)]);
```

This code is from a tutorial in the link 
http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/wuxf/talks/IAMCS-ParallelProgramming-2013-3.pdf

for matlab with mpi.

Thanks a lot!